# Como verificar se uma variável é tipo string ou number?

Tags: javascript, html

Fiz um "mini site" para perguntar o nome da pessoa e enviar um `alert` porém, quero de alguma forma enviar um `alert` de erro se a pessoa coloca números ao invés dos caracteres do nome.

```js
<h2 class="Titulo">Bem Vindo</h2>
   <div id="Maincx">
       <div class="dados-pessoa">
           <label for="nome">Digite seu Nome</label>
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
           <button onclick="submit()">Enviar</button>
       </div>
   </div>`
```

```js
function submit() {
  var input = document.getElementById('name');
  var texto = input.value;

  console.log("Nome inserido: " + texto);

  alert("Olá Sr. " + texto + " Balalaika");
    
}
```

Comment: só usar typeof(texto) vai retornar string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns comentários tentando nortear o usuário para uma resposta, mas acho que nenhum deles realmente ajuda para esse caso.

Para verificar se o que foi digitado no *input* foi uma string ou um número, não basta verificar o tipo do *value*, pois o *value* sempre será do tipo *string*

No JavaScript existe a função `isNaN`, que serve para verificar se uma variável *não* é um número. Não é apenas para verificar se o tipo da variável não é *number*, ela também valida se strings são representações numéricas, por exemplo:

```
isNaN('Lukas') // true
isNaN('Luk4s') // true
isNaN('123')   // false
isNaN('1.0')   // false
isNaN('1e5')   // false - isso é uma representação válida do número 100000
```

Outras alternativas seriam utilizar expressões regulares como `value.match(/[^0-9]/)` para validar se o *value* tem pelo menos um caractere que não seja um dígito, ou `value.match(/^[^0-9]*$/)` para validar se o *value* não tem nenhum dígito.

Exemplo:

```
function submit() {
  var input = document.getElementById('name');
  var texto = input.value;

  console.log("Nome inserido: " + texto);
  
  if (isNaN(texto)) {
    alert("Olá Sr. " + texto + " Balalaika");
  } else {
    alert("Por favor, digite um nome válido");
  }
}
```